# WMIC ProcessID Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, process, wmic

I am using WMIC in Batch to get a process ID.
How can I use the CommandLine parameter in WMIC Command.

I already tried somthing like this:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in ('wmic process where "name^="Example.exe" and CommandLine like '%Example%'" get ProcessId') do (echo attach %%i >> ".\my-script.txt")
```

I get a Process only using the parameter name. But the problem is i have three processes with the same name.

Comment: `"name^="Example.exe"` seems wrong to me.

Comment: Try it like this   for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in ('wmic process where name^="Example.exe" get ProcessId') do (echo attach %%i >> ".\my-script_1.txt")    . Yout will get the PID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`wmic process where "name='Example.exe' and CommandLine like '%%Example%%'" get ProcessID /Format:value`) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%z in ("%%a") do set "%%z"
)
echo %processid%
```

you need to double the `%` otherwise it will be parsed by cmd.exe as variable.